# What would prevent an object from being saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object

In my code I have this :

```
def confirm
  @pal = Pal.find(params[:palid])
  @newuser = User.new(newuser_params)
  @newuser.username = @pal.phone

  if @newuser.save
    redirect_to(:controller => 'access', :action => 'index')
  else
    flash[:error] = "Retry."
    render template: 'pals/new_password_asign'
  end
end  

private

def newuser_params
  params.require(:newuser).permit(:username, :password_digest, :password_stored)
end
```

and after submitting my sign up form, I get redirected and the error "Retry" which I've specified.

Knowing that I create users and save them via `rails console` perfectly fine.

And this has got me thinking what would possibly prevent this from being saved?
What issues might occur during the saving?

======================================================

**Rails v4**

**Ruby v2.02**

**I am using Bcrypt-ruby for authentication.**

======================================================

**Update #1**

=======================================================

After adding the suggested solution of @mandeep, I now do get the error explanation, and in this explanation I get

" **Password can't be blank** "

Despite the fact that I do write the password before submiting

Check my sign up form

```
<%= form_for(:newuser, :url => {:action => 'confirm', :palid => @pal.id}) do |f| %>
                    <% if @newuser.errors.any? %>
                      <div id="error_explanation">
                        <h2><%= pluralize(@newuser.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

                        <ul>
                          <% @newuser.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                            <li><%= msg %></li>
                          <% end %>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    <% end %> 

        <table summary="user form fields">
                <tr>
                    <th><%= f.label(:username, "User Name") %></th> 
                    <td><%= f.text_field :username, :value => @newuser.username, :class => "controls", :disabled => "true" %></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th><%= f.label(:password, "password") %></th>
                    <td><%= f.password_field(:password) %></td>
                </tr>

        </table>

                    <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
                      </div>

                <% end %>
                <% @newuser.password_stored = @newuser.password %>
            </div>
                </body>
```

==============================================

**Update #2**

## Log and params after being request by @mandeep

```
Started GET "/pals" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:44 +0000
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by palsController#index as HTML
  pal Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `pals`.* FROM `pals`
  Rendered pals/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 280ms (Views: 260.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/pals" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000
Processing by palsController#index as HTML
  pal Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `pals`.* FROM `pals`
  Rendered pals/index.html.erb within layouts/application (6.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 103ms (Views: 101.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


Started GET "/assets/access.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/pals.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/users.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:45 +0000


Started GET "/assets/access.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:46 +0000


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:46 +0000


Started GET "/assets/pals.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:46 +0000


Started GET "/assets/users.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:46 +0000


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:15:46 +0000


Started GET "/pals/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:11 +0000
Processing by PalsController#new as HTML
  Rendered pals/_form.html.erb (24.7ms)
  Rendered pals/new.html.erb within layouts/application (43.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 106ms (Views: 101.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)


Started POST "/pals" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000
Processing by PalsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8X6LD0g6E1HybdAF/FOlM09iuQLWExBY8dY5CqSDZsM=", "pal"=>{"owner"=>"John", "title"=>"", "phone"=>"22", "price"=>"", "logtype"=>"", "description"=>"", "address"=>"", "latitude"=>"", "longitude"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create pal"}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `pals` (`address`, `created_at`, `description`, `logtype`, `owner`, `phone`, `title`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('', '2014-07-03 16:16:19', '', '', 'John', '22', '', '2014-07-03 16:16:19')
   (56.6ms)  COMMIT
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`username` = '22'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/pals/confirm?palid=5
Completed 302 Found in 77ms (ActiveRecord: 58.1ms)


Started GET "/pals/confirm?palid=5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000
Processing by PalsController#confirm as HTML
  Parameters: {"palid"=>"5"}
  pal Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `pals`.* FROM `pals`  WHERE `pals`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
  Rendered pals/confirm.html.erb within layouts/application (6.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 63ms (Views: 52.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)


Started GET "/assets/access.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/pals.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/users.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/access.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/pals.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/users.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:19 +0000


Started POST "/pals/confirm?palid=5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000
Processing by PalsController#confirm as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8X6LD0g6E1HybdAF/FOlM09iuQLWExBY8dY5CqSDZsM=", "newuser"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Save Newuser", "palid"=>"5"}
  pal Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `pals`.* FROM `pals`  WHERE `pals`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered pals/confirm.html.erb within layouts/application (1.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 60ms (Views: 50.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)


Started GET "/assets/access.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/pals.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/users.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:29 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:30 +0000


Started GET "/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:30 +0000


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:30 +0000


Started GET "/assets/pals.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:30 +0000


Started GET "/assets/access.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:30 +0000


Started GET "/assets/users.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:30 +0000


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:30 +0000


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 16:16:30 +0000
```

Comment: You can debug it by adding @newuser.save! instead of @newuser.save to know about the error.

Comment: You have `pal = Pal.find(params[:palid])`. that `pal` without `@`. then you have `@newuser.username = @pal.phone`. obviously, `@newuser` is not properly defined. unless `pal` and `@pal` are two different variables

Comment: Actually that was a typo while editing my post, I do have `@` in my code, Check the updates to know more about my problem please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your code

```
def confirm
  pal = Pal.find(params[:palid])  # you have find your pal and store it in "pal"
  @newuser = User.new(newuser_params)
  @newuser.username = @pal.phone  # you are using instance variable "@pal" which is not defined
  # your other logic
end
```

Instead you should have your code like:

```
def confirm
  @pal = Pal.find(params[:palid])  
  @newuser = User.new(newuser_params)
  @newuser.username = @pal.phone
  # your other logic
end
```

Also in your form you should put this code

```
<% if @newuser.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@newuser.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
      <% @newuser.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

*This will display if there are any **validation errors** in your form*. For details refer to [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views)

**Update:**

If you look at the parameters which are being passed from your form, notice this

`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8X6LD0g6E1HybdAF/FOlM09iuQLWExBY8dY5CqSDZsM=", "newuser"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Save Newuser", "palid"=>"5"}`

There are couple of things wrong in your form:

a. Either you didn't enter your username in form or you haven't made your form properly because in params it's only showing **password field** `"newuser"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]"}`

b. You **haven't permit your password field** instead of permitting password you have permitted :*password_digest, :password_stored*. Your newuser_params should look like this:

```
def newuser_params
  params.require(:newuser).permit(:username, :password)
end
```

c. what is `"palid"=>"5"` doing in your params? Is it a field in your form or what because it's not associated to newuser params

Comment: About the '@' it was a typo, I already had it in my code, it is only during the copying in which I've lost it.

Thanks about the error displaying, It's helping , but it says 'Password Can't Be Blank' , Which is not blank, I do write it..

Please check my update.

Comment: @TECHPUSHTA can you post your logs with params when you submit your form?

Comment: I already posted the params, I guess.. I do not seem to get your question though.. Please explain.

Comment: @TECHPUSHTA clear your terminal or console and then submit your form after submitting it'll show up what request is going to server in your terminal and params, can you post that

Comment: **About c**, it is a way to keep the creation of the user conditional to the currently-in-creation Pal, so after creating the user, his id will be passed to the pal to keep their relationship.

**About a** ,  but if it was about the username, why isn't it showing me 'username can't be blank'

**About b**, I've done what you've instructed ,and you are right it should do it, however it did not solved it.

Please recheck my form and tell me if the way I have put the username in the value would submit it to the db? apparently not, but ease do.

Answer (score 0):

Check the validation errors in `@newuser`, namely `@newuser.errors`. There are methods that skip validations. Maybe you are using them in the console.